# Unit Test Code Coverage not 100% with Localization String

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

We are working to get our unit test code coverage as close to 100% as possible.  We are doing fairly well, but because of the localization strings (which are designed to fail gracefully) the results look far worse than they really are.

Here is an example of code in my Model that is not getting covered:

```
    #region strings
    public string AllStr { get { return Localizer.GetString("Resources.Order.Status", "all", "all"); } }
    public string ArchivedStr { get { return Localizer.GetString("Resources.Order.Status", "archived", "archived"); } }
    public string Closed30Str { get { return Localizer.GetString("Resources.Order.Status", "closed30", "closed30"); } }
    public string Closed90Str { get { return Localizer.GetString("Resources.Order.Status", "closed90", "closed90"); } }
    public string GoStr { get { return Localizer.GetString("Resources.Global", "go", "go"); } }
    public string OpenStr { get { return Localizer.GetString("Resources.Order.Status", "open", "open"); } }
    public string OrderStatusStr { get { return Localizer.GetString("Resources.Order.Status", "orderStatus", "orderStatus"); } }
    public string SelectedCustStr { get { return Localizer.GetString("Resources.Order.Status", "selectedCust", "selectedCust"); } }
    public string StartTypingStr { get { return Localizer.GetString("Resources.Order.Status", "startTyping", "startTyping"); } }
    public string TitleStr { get { return Localizer.GetString("Resources.Order.Status", "title", "title"); } }
    #endregion
```

I really don't want to add the hundreds of strings in my application to unit testing, but I also don't want them to impact the coverage results.

How do I exclude these string from the code coverage analysis so I get a more accurate picture of the tests that matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd984116%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).  Applying this to your code will exclude it from your code coverage results.

```
[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
public string AllStr { get { return Localizer.GetString("Resources.Order.Status", "all", "all"); } }
```

The question really is... why would you ever want to add these to attain 100% code coverage?  100% code coverage doesn't tell a developer anything about a project. It's a bragging bullet point for your manager.

Comment: That's marketing. If you put "We're 100% covered by tests" to the product site - you can sell it more expensive

Comment: While I am not super concerned about 100% (it would be nice however), I do want to know if the code I want tested is covered at 100%, 50%, 10%, etc.  With the strings in there 100% critical code test could look like 10%.

Comment: As for the `Exclude...`, I was hoping I didn't have to add it for every string.  I guess there isn't a way to cover a region of strings or all Localization strings?  Or standardize a simple test that would mean I don't have to individually test every string in my system?

Comment: The only thing I can think of there would be to extract it into it's own class that you can exclude entirely.